# Introductory textbook on geometry of hyperbolic space

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, textbook-recommendation

I am looking for an introductory textbook to the geometry of the hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n$. The book should include explicit description of geodesics and horospheres in various models (hyperboloid, Poincaré, Klein).

Apologies if the question is not appropriate for this site.

Comment: This is a nice introduction. https://www.math.brown.edu/~rkenyon/papers/cannon.pdf

Comment: An introductio to Geoetric Topology by Bruno Matelli is very good (Part 1 of the ook for Hyperbolic Geometry)

Answer (score 8):

I really like Ratcliffe’s account of the 3 models ($H^n$, $U^n$, $B^n$) in *Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds* ([2006](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2007d:57029), Chap. 3–5). It has what you ask for, and also copious exercises and historical notes.

Comment: I second this. It's a large book, but I remember it being very readable.

Answer (score 7):

W. Thurston, Three-dimensional geometry and topology.

Answer (score 3):

*Prasolov, V. V.; Tikhomirov, V. M.*, Geometry. Transl. from the Russian by O. V. Sipacheva. Transl. edited by A. B. Sossinski, Translations of Mathematical Monographs. 200. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xi, 257 p. (2001). [ZBL0977.51001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0977.51001).

Answer (score 2):

You might try the following:

1. Jürgen Richter-Gebert: *Perspectives on Projective Geometry,*
2. David Mumford, Caroline Series, David Wright: *Indra´s Pearls.*